# Merge two large CSV files with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I want to merge two large CSV files with PHP. This files are too big to even put into memory all at once. In pseudocode, I can think of something like this:

```
for i in file1
  file3.write(file1.line(i) + ',' + file2.line(i))
end
```

But when I'm looping through a file using `fgetcsv`, it's not really clear how I would grab line `n` from a certain file without loading the whole thing into memory first.

Any ideas?

Edit: I forgot to mention that each of the two files has the same number of lines and they have a one-to-one relationship. That is, line 62,324 in file1 goes with line 62,324 in file2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what operating system you're on, but if you're using Linux, using the [`paste`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) command is probably a lot easier than trying to do this in PHP.

If this is a viable solution and you don't absolutely need to do it in PHP, you could try the following:

```
paste -d ',' file1 file2 > combined_file
```

Comment: Yeah! Awesome! I love solutions like this. I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `fgets` function. You could read a single line of each file, process them, and write them to your new file, then move on to the next line until you've reached the end of your file.

[PHP: fgets](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

Specifically look at the example titled **Example #1 Reading a file line by line** in the PHP manual. It's also important to note the return value of the the `fgets` functions.

> Returns a string of up to *length* - 1
>   bytes read from the file pointed to by
>   *handle*. If there is no more data to
>   read in the file pointer, then **FALSE**
>   is returned.

So, if it doesn't return **FALSE** you know you still have more lines to process.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fgets()`.

```
$file1 = fopen('file1.txt', 'r');
$file2 = fopen('file2.txt', 'r');
$merged = fopen('merged.txt', 'w');

while (
    ($line1 = fgets($file1)) !== false
    && ($line2 = fgets($file2)) !== false) {

    fwrite($merged, $line1 . ',' . $line2);
}
```

`fgets()` reads one line from a file.  As you can see, this code uses it on both files at the same time, writing the merged lines to a third file.  The manual here:

http://php.net/fgets

http://php.net/fopen

http://php.net/fwrite

Answer (score 1):

Try using [fgets()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to read one line from each file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for this is to map first line begins for each line ( and some kind of key if you need ) and then make a new csv using fread and fwrite ( we know beginning and ending of each line now , so we need just seek and read )

Another way is to put it into MySQL ( if it is possible ) and then back to new CSV