# How can I merge 3 CSV files into 1 CSV file using PHP?

Tags: php, csv, yii

I want to merge 3 csv files, each file is :

```
File1.csv :
2014-01-01,10
2014-01-02,15
2014-01-03,25
.
.
.

File2.csv :
2014-01-01,20
2014-01-02,26
2014-01-03,46
.
.
.

File3.csv :
2014-01-01,30
2014-01-02,35
2014-01-03,40
.
.
.
```

I want to merge into 1 csv file, call merge.csv :

```
2014-01-01,10,20,30
2014-01-02,15,26,35
2014-01-03,25,46,40
```

I have tried these:

- [Merge csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695473/merge-csv-files)
- [Merge two large CSV files with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740957/merge-two-large-csv-files-with-php)
- [Combining 2 CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417734/combining-2-csv-files)

But it still is not working. How can I do it?

Comment: "But it still is not working". What exactly is not working?

Comment: not execute :( i using make function in Yii framework

Comment: What you want is not to merge the files, but to merge the values of each date and write it to a new file. That's a bit more complex, since it involves parsing the file contents. I don't have time to write an answer not, but that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: If you want a complete solution from scratch, you should hire a developer. If you have written any code yourself, that doesn't work the way you expect it, you should narrow the problem down as much as possible, and then post the problematic code along with a description of what you want it to do and what it is actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this should do it

```
$file1 = fopen('file1.csv', 'r');
$file2 = fopen('file2.csv', 'r');
...
$merged = fopen('merged.csv', 'w');

$files = array($file1,$file2,...);
$output=array();

foreach($files as $file){
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        list($index,$value)= explode(',',trim($line));
        $output[$index][]=$value;
    }
}
foreach($output as $key => $values){
    fwrite($merged, $key . ',' . implode(',',$values).PHP_EOL);
}
```